# Como mantener el sonido al leer una realidad aumentada

Tags: c#, unity3d, vuforia

Tengo la siguiente situación. Estoy leyendo un patrón con de RA con **vuforia**. Al momento de la lectura del patrón, comienza a reproducir un sonido mientras que estoy leyendo pero si dejo de leer el patrón el sonido se detiene. Mi pregunta es la siguiente existe alguna forma que una vez que el sonido comience a reproducirse no se detenga hasta que no llegue al final. A continuación les dejo el código.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class reproduccionAudio : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{

 private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

        void Start(){
            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
            if (mTrackableBehaviour){
                mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }
        }

        public void OnTrackableStateChanged( TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus){         

            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED  )
            {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }else{
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        }
    }
 }
```

Gracias

Comment: Si solo comentas el else   ya debería estar haciendo solo la reproducción del sonido.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono sin problema.

Comment: lo pondré como respuesta para que se entienda como pregunta cerrada. Solo lo marcas como respuesta acertada.

Comment: Ok no hay problema con mucho gusto lo hare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no se detenga la reproducción de tu `Audiosource` debes solo comentar  el camino `else` de tu código ya que este se activa cuando dejas de hacer la acción del patron.

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged( TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus){         

    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED  )
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
    //else{
    //    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
    //}
}
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, el sonido no se me detiene y se me sigue reproduciendo pero ahora lo que pasa es que se me encima uno con otro. De que forma puede detener el que se esta reproduciendo sin que se me encime con el nuevo sonido a reproducir.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez Si tienes alguna duda formula una nueva pregunta tal como hiciste esta.